# При наведении на div class="spin" должен прокрутиться div class="circle". Вроде все правильно, но не работает. Подскажите в чем проблема?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, css-animation

```css
    body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 }
 .wrap {
  background: #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
 }

 .circle {
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #33cd45;
  border-left: 10px solid #33cd45;
  border-top: 10px solid #fff;
  border-right: 10px solid #fff;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
 }
 
 .circle2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom: 30px solid #3398cd;
  border-left: 30px solid #3398cd;
  border-top: 30px solid #ff0000;
  border-right: 30px solid #ff0000;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
 }
 .spin {
  width: 200px;
  line-height: 50px;
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
  color: aliceblue;
  margin: 50px auto;
 }
 .spin:hover {
  background: #3398cd;
  cursor: pointer;
 }
 .spin:hover .circle {
  transform: rotate(100deg);
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>spider</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="wrap"> 
  <div class="spin">spin</div>
  <div class="circle2">
  
   <div class="circle"></div>
  </div>
 </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Быть может:

```
.spin:hover + .circle2 { ....
```

Comment: тогда два круга крутится(
исправил, нужно что бы только .circle крутился
.spin:hover .circle { ....

Comment: благодаря вам, додумался
решение
.spin:hover + .circle2 .circle {
  transform: rotate(100deg);
 }